# How to parse author name and book title from scraped HTML using XPath?

Tags: xpath

The HTML you see below is text I have scraped from a remote site, as-is, into a local variable.

Now I need to parse the `authorName` and `bookTitle` from the HTML tags into their own variables, given the following consistent format of the scraped text:

```
<p>
  William Faulkner - 'Light In August'
  <br/>
  William Faulkner - 'Sanctuary'
  <br/>
  William Faulkner - 'The Sound and the Fury'
</p>
```

Is it possible to do this in XPath?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for short and easy XPath expressions.

Comment: I would also look into converting it into XHTML before you try to use xPath.  Even though it's valid XML now you never know what might change.  Some good resources: http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ and http://xml.coverpages.org/sgml.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. And easy, too:

```
//p/text()
```

Will give you three separate text nodes:

```
"
  William Faulkner - 'Light In August'
  ",
"
  William Faulkner - 'Sanctuary'
  ",
"
  William Faulkner - 'The Sound and the Fury'
"
```

Remember that preceding and trailing whitespace (including any line breaks) is always part of the text node. Trim the result.

I take it that you do not need help with splitting the resulting strings into author and title.

Comment: Interesting, can you provide some documentation that shows this is how text() works?

Comment: @Abe: Before I start, can you indicate why you think that this is how `text()` does *not* work?

Comment: Relax tough guy... I didn't say I don't think it works, I just didn't know it could work like this and would like to be able to read up on it.  Not challenging you, just seeking knowledge...

Comment: @Abe: I'm perfectly relaxed. `text()` selects all text node children of a node. And the `<p>` has five children here, three of type text interspersed with two of type element (`<br/>`).

Answer (score 2):

In XPath 1.0 you can select the text node childs of `p`:

```
/p/text()
```

You can also get the string before (author) and after (title) `-` character **for each text node**

```
substring-before(/p/text()[1],'-')
```

Result:

```
  William Faulkner 

substring-after(/p/text()[1],'-')
```

Result:

```
 'Light In August'
```

In XPath 2.0:

```
/p/text()/substring-before(.,'-')
```

Result in a sequence of 3 items:

```
William Faulkner William Faulkner William Faulkner
```

And

```
/p/text()/substring-after(.,'-')
```

Result also in a sequence of 3 items:

```
'Light In August' 'Sanctuary' 'The Sound and the Fury'
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can get the $N-th author name with this XPath expression**:

```
substring-before(normalize-space(p/text()[$N]), ' -')
```

**You can get the $N-th title with this XPath expression**:

```
substring-after(normalize-space(p/text()[$N]), ' - ')
```

You can get first the count of all text nodes with:

```
count(p/text())
```

then you can issue the first two XPath expressions, substituting `$N` with the numbers in the interval

```
[1,count(p/text())]
```

Comment: @Tomalak: Thanks, I saw this immediately (before your comment) and it was already corrected when I read it. Monday morning, you know... :(

Comment: Comment already deleted, right after I saw you fixed it. Seems there is some caching involved with the comments, if I change them you do not seem to see the change right away.